# Does a multivariate function attain its bounds?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

A continuous function on a closed bounded interval on the real line is bounded and attains its global maximum and minimum. Is this true for a multivariable function as well? Intuitively it makes sense that it should, but how can I show this?

Comment: Take a look at the extreme value theorem. It says that if $X$ is a compact topological space, $f:X \to \Bbb{R}$ is continuous, then $f$ attains its maximum and minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a closed non-empty bounded subset of $\Bbb R^n$. By the Heine-Borel theorem,
$X$ is a compact metric space. If $f:X\to\Bbb R$ is a continuous function then
$f(X)$ is a compact non-empty subspace of $\Bbb R$. Compact subspaces of $\Bbb R$
are closed and bounded, so $f(X)$ has a maximum and a minimum element.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:\textbf{R}^{n}\to\textbf{R}$ be a continuous function from the Euclidean space $\textbf{R}^{n}$ onto the real line $\textbf{R}$.

As mentioned by @AnginaSeng, if $X\subseteq\textbf{R}^{n}$ is nonempty, closed and bounded, then it is compact according to the Heine-Borel theorem.

Once $f$ is continuous, $f(X)\subseteq\textbf{R}$ is compact, hence bounded and closed. Thus $f(X)$ admits an infimum $m$ and a supremum $M$. Since $m$ and $M$ are adherent points, then $m\in f(X)$ and $M\in f(X)$.

In other words, there exists a $x_{min}\in X$ such that $f(x_{min}) = m \leq f(x)$ for all $x\in X$.

Similarly, there exists a $x_{max}\in X$ such that $f(x_{max}) = M \geq f(x)$ for all $x\in X$.

Hopefully this helps.